# google.api_core.exceptions.ResourceExhausted: 429 Received message larger than max when querying bigquery

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have an issue where I try to query BQ and put it in a pandas dataframe inside an AI job. The error is the following:

google.api_core.exceptions.ResourceExhausted: 429 Received message larger than max (4364379 vs. 4194304)

Which seems to indicate that there is some metadata being sent alongside the query result that exceeds 4MB since the query itself is orders of magnitude larger than 4MB.

The question is, how can I change this when I send the query via the google cloud bigquery package? My code looks like the following:

```
bqstorage_client = BigQueryReadClient(credentials=credentials)

client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project='PROJECT_NAME'
)


sql_query = 'QUERY STRING'


df = client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client)
```

This does work if I change it into a simple query but there seems to be some arbitrary limit on the metadata sent back, is there any way to change this limit?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, this looks like it might be a problem with the grpc channel settings, but requires more details to investigate.  Could you file an issue on https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues with more information?

Useful things to include would be the versions of packages in your environment (e.g. `pip freeze` or similar), as well as some basic details about the query/result shape.  If you've got any environment variables set with a `GRPC` prefix please include them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out big query send an enormous amount of metadata if you have a bunch of array columns, I unnested the table in the query and this problem disappeared.

Comment: I'd still encourage you to file an issue with the details.  This should not be necessary as a mitigation.